# Monitoring File Uploading

Tags: newrelic

We would like to be able to find out the current behaviour of our file uploader in terms of performance. We would like to be able to find out the max number of files that can be uploaded at the same time without stressing the server. We would also like to know the current usage.

We looked at new Relic as a possible solution and tried using custom hooks like this:

```
::NewRelic::Agent.agent.stats_engine.get_stats_no_scope('photo/new/time').record_data_point(Time.new - session[:upload_start_time])
```

Sadly, I cannot see the data appear on the New Relic dashboard or Transactions view. Is there another place to look at from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking to the New Relic support team we managed to solve the problem. It seems custom metrics must start with a path that has the word `Custom/` as a prefix. So in my case it would be:

```
::NewRelic::Agent.agent.stats_engine.get_stats_no_scope('Custom/photo/new/time').record_data_point(Time.new - session[:upload_start_time])
```

You can then create a custom dashboard widget with that new metrics. Just type in the name of your metrics starting with Custom (it should auto complete to your metric).